Mocking is not working with Pekko. Instead of fulfilling request from mocking, it's hitting actual database
When we were using Akka Actors, and while using it, our mocking and testing was working fine. Now we switched to Pekko Actors, and while using it, our mocking is not working because sending request hitting the actual database.
Everything is replaced from Akka actors to Pekko Actors properly but mocking is not working in case of Pekko Actors. Why?
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.19" % Test,
  "org.scalatestplus" %% "mockito-4-11" % "3.2.18.0" % Test,
  "org.mockito" %% "mockito-scala" % "1.17.37" % Test,
  "org.apache.pekko" %% "pekko-http-spray-json" % "1.0.1",
  "org.apache.pekko" %% "pekko-stream" % "1.0.3",
  "org.apache.pekko" %% "pekko-actor" % "1.0.3",
  "org.apache.pekko" %% "pekko-http" % "1.0.1",
  "org.apache.pekko" %% "pekko-stream-testkit" % "1.0.3",
  "org.apache.pekko" %% "pekko-http-testkit" % "1.0.1" % Test
)

class ReaderTest extends AnyWordSpec with Matchers with ScalatestRouteTest with MockitoSugar with JsonSupport {
  private val readerRepository: ReaderRepositoryTrait = mock[ReaderRepositoryTrait]

 val dataList: List[Data] =
    List(Data(Some("1"), Some("Ali"), Some("Umer"), Some("Ali Umer"), Some("1/2/1998"), Some("1/2/1998"), Some("Pakistan")
      , Some("Male"), Some("Pakistan"), "images/testImage", "images/testFaceImage"),

      Data(Some("2"), Some("Hamza"), Some("Khan"), Some("Hamza Khan"), Some("1/2/1998"), Some("1/2/1998"), Some("Pakistan")
        , Some("Male"), Some("Pakistan"), "images/testPassportImage", "images/testFaceImage"))

  val getAllJsonResponse: JsObject = JsObject("Total Records -> 2" -> JsArray(DataList.toJson))

"The Service" should {
    "return a Response in JSON for GET request with path (/get-data-from-db)" in {

      when(ReaderRepository.getData(any[Span])).thenReturn(Future.successful(DataList))

      Get("/get-data-from-db") ~> allRoutes ~> check {
        status shouldEqual StatusCodes.OK
        contentType shouldEqual ContentTypes.`application/json`
        responseAs[String] shouldEqual routeResponseMessage.getResponse(StatusCodes.OK.intValue
          , ServerMessage.GET_SUCCESSFULLY_ALL, getAllJsonResponse).toString()
      }
    }
 }
}

trait ReaderRepositoryTrait {
  def getData(span: Span): Future[List[Data]]
}


I don't think it's related to Akka or Pekko at all. Where is your mocked instance somehow injected? From what you shared, the mocked instance is indeed never used.

Coudl you provide a Minimal Reproducible Example? I would guess that the problem is how you built the value allRoutes. You mocked ReaderRepositoryTrait but in the code provided it doesn't look like it's being used by some other class. So, you need something like class AllRoutes(repoInstance) and a method or value that returns allRoutes. Then in your test, you would do something like val allRoutes = new AllRoutes(repoMock) and your assert should look like Get("/path") ~> allRoutes ~> ...
